# How to create offline map app using map box?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, offline, mapbox

I have created a map app using map box iOS SDK. However I need to download the map for offline usage.

I have created a map box account and created a project and put some markers on the map using the online editor.

To offline use how can I caches its data ?

Comment: How much of the documentation have you read? https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/#tile_caching__class Do you have any code that you have used to show you have attempted to solve this yourself?

Comment: @Popeye I've read the doc but did not understand what to do ... I've also found the github examples as well. However I am noob for this kinda of thing, If you have time please help me. I have upload the project to the github and here is the link for the project I am working on Link https://github.com/ankahathara/MapBoxOfflineTest

Comment: I also can't find a working solution for caching. Does anybody have better examples then those mentioned?

Comment: @Ankahathara did you find any solution to download and show offline map.Please update if you done this Thanks